# The declarations in the link below don't need the storage-class-specifier `static`. Am I correct?

Tags: c++, templates, static, c++14

The following is an excerpt of [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) cppreference page about variable template

> When used at class scope, variable template declares a static data
>   member template.
>
> ```
> using namespace std::literals;
> struct matrix_constants
> {
>     template<class T>
>     using pauli = hermitian_matrix<T, 2>; // alias template
>
>     template<class T> // static data member template
>     static constexpr pauli<T> sigma1 = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 } }; 
>
>     template<class T>
>     static constexpr pauli<T> sigma2 = { { 0, -1i }, { 1i, 0 } };
>
>    template<class T>
>    static constexpr pauli<T> sigma3 = { { 1, 0 }, { 0, -1 } };
> };
> ```

The C++ Standard (N4140) says the following in paragraph §14.1 (1.4):

> A variable template at class scope is a static data member template.

Thus, it seems to me the declarations in the link above don't need the storage-class-specifier `static`. Am I correct?

P.S.: I've just started my investigation on templates.

Comment: Are you sure you really want to start your *investigation on templates* with variable templates? May be with something more straightforward?

Comment: @SergeyA I know the Standard is not the best place to study C++, but for now, that's what I'm doing, i.e., I'm following the Standard.

Comment: @Barry But [C++0z](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#1) still didn't correct the example shown above.

Comment: @JohnKalane Yes, the example is unfortunately incorrect still (see Richard Smith's comment in linked question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I still do not think that you've choosen the right course to study templates, I am going to answer direct question.

The wording of Standard (and cppreference) mean that template variables should be defined as `static` when they are class members. It is a requirement for the developer.